# Programmaticaly tagging stack in Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I would like to programmatically add a tag to a Pulumi stack. Specifically, I want to add a tag named `environment` with value equal to a name of the Pulumi stack.
E.g. if name of the Pulumi stack is `staging`, I would like to add a tag `environment` with value `staging` to the stack.
I will then use the tag `environment` for grouping all the staging stacks in Pulumi console.

I know that it is possible to tag Pulumi stacks using Pulumi CLI, as described in [Pulumi CLI doc](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_stack_tag/).
However, I would like to add the tags to Pulumi stack programmatically, from the code defining the stack.
I know I can access the name of the current stack via variable `Deployment.Instance.StackName`, but cannot find how to assign a tag to the current stack.

I use the current version of Pulumi, which is 3.5.1. Is there any way?

Comment: what programing language are you planning to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tag a pulumi stack as part of running the program, use the Pulumi Service provider. The resource you want is [StackTag](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/pulumiservice/api-docs/stacktag/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This new Pulumi Service provider is a great addition to the Pulumi ecosystem.